# Render erb in Vagrant provisioning

Tags: vagrant

As part of provisioning a VM, I need to create a configuration file at provision time.  On my host machine, I'm able to pass variables to an `erb` file:

```
erb x=1 y=2 some_conf.erb
```

Is it possible to render the `erb` file on the host machine, and then pipe the result to the guest?

If I put the `erb` command in a `config.vm.provision "shell"` , the command is run on the guest machine (which does not have Ruby), e.g.

```
# this command runs on the guest
# where as I want erb to run on the host
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  erb x=1 y=2 some_conf.erb > /etc/some_conf
SHELL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant file is actually a ruby script so you could use the ruby erb template engine. Make sure to create the class necessary for your template

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
require 'erb'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    template = ERB.new File.read("template/some_conf.erb")
    p template.result(binding)
end
```

If you don't want to set up the new class etc and you have ruby2.2 installed you can just call erb from CLI directly, it will run on your host not the guest

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    exec ('erb x=1 y=2 template/some_conf.erb > some_conf')

end
```

once the `some_conf` file is generated on the host, you can use the [vagrant file provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/file.html) to push this single file on the host

```
config.vm.provision "file", source: "some_conf", destination: "/somewhere/on/the/guest/some_conf"
```

Comment: Using the first example, how do I pipe the output to a file on the guest?

Comment: you can use vagrant file provisioner, adding example